# Speed Checked By Radar: Synhermeneia?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity, neologisms

Is there a word to describe an ambiguous phrase whose alternate meanings all happen to be relevant and true in the context?

The example that fascinates me is the road sign "Speed Checked By Radar". The ambiguous words "speed", "checked", and "by" permit these completely different interpretations — all of which are relevant and true!

- Velocity tested using radar
- Velocity constrained using radar
- Velocity tested next to the radar
- Velocity constrained next to the radar
- Rapidly tested using radar
- Rapidly constrained using radar
- Rapidly tested next to the radar
- Rapidly constrained next to the radar

I made an attempt to coin a neologism to describe such.  How about "synhermeneia", i.e. having related interpretations, or "Polyhermeneuthos", i.e. multiple true interpretations?

Comment: Some of those simply do not work.

Comment: You're right, some interpretations don't make as much sense as others.  Still, if we list only the meaningful ones, they all are true and relevant to the context.  It's that "coincidental" appropriateness I'm interested in.

Comment: I just don't see any ambiguity: [Your] Speed [is]  Checked By Radar

Comment: @Lambie The ambiguities result from terse language that's often used in signage. The "rapidly" interpretations come from assuming that "speed checked" is short for "speedily checked" or "speed-checked".

Comment: Most of the interpretations fail due to common sense. Radar is just a measurement system, it can't constrain anything. These are almost all deliberate attempts to misunderstand the phrase, in an Alice in Wonderland kind of way.

Comment: Few non-native speakers realise the importance of context. Anyone ignoring or misunderstanding the notice will be put right by the police. The ambiguity is trivial. No neologism is required. The word the OP is looking for is "**ambiguous**."

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143287/discussion-on-question-by-purplie-speed-checked-by-radar-synhermeneia); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you *could* interpret a phrase differently is rather uninteresting if those other interpretations are absurd or obviously unintended. Many (most?) sentences could have such interpretations; you could interpret "He flew to San Francisco" as meaning that he grew wings and used them to move through the air. So there isn't really anything unique or unusual about your example.

In this case, the interpretation "velocity tested using radar" is obviously the one intended by the sign's authors. It isn't ambiguous, since that is the only viable reading; at the very least, any other viable readings would have the same truth conditions. It's just an ordinary phrase that you could, if you tried hard enough, misread.

Comment: This type of ambiguity is often employed in comedy. "Take my wife, please." "I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know." "I just flew in from Chicago; boy, are my arms tired."